# Implementing timestampdiff in sqllite through PDO::sqliteCreateFunction

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, unit-testing, pdo

We're using MySQL as our main database for a Laravel project.

Laravel uses in-memory sqlite combined with factories/seeders for functional/acceptance tests by default, to keep tests isolated and fast. We're currently trying to write small unit tests with mocks as much as possible, but we also have a few hundred older "functional" tests which fire up these little sqlite instances and use Laravel testing functions like `seeInDatabase()`.

Laravel's Eloquent ORM is pretty good at abstracting the database functions away, but there's some functionality which sqlite does not provide by default.

I'm trying to extend the sqlite functionality using this PDO [method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php), to support a few often used MySQL functions in our codebase:

```
$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction('timestampdiff', function($unit, $start, $end){
    return ...
});
```

I understand how to implement the UDF (I've already implemented trig functions, regex, datediff, etc).

The problem is that the first parameter passed to `timestampdiff` is a unit, an unquoted plain label like `MINUTE` or `YEAR`.

This parameter is interpreted as a column by sqlite. Faking MySQL's `date_add()` is also problematic, as the third parameter to that function is unquoted with spaces, like `INTERVAL 2 HOUR`.

My current best effort is to replace timestampdiff queries with `floor((unix_timestamp(end) - unix_timestamp(start))/60)`, as both floor and unix_timestamp are creatable through `sqliteCreateFunction`.

This all feels very hacky though. I realize I might be pushing the limits of PHP/PDO/sqlite here, but would love suggestions on a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined functions cannot change the syntax rules.

Your only choice is to get the ORM to use different functions for different databases, or to install your own UDFs in MySQL.

Comment: I guess trying to transparently rewrite MySQL syntax into Sqlite functions is not really what sqliteCreateFunction is made for... now that you mention it, it might be better to either extend eloquent, or use some builder macros.